# Why does man -P behave differently when the output is redirected or piped?

Tags: command-line, manpage, stdout

```
man -P whoami ls
```

This command will output user's name, just like `whoami`. But when you use pipe to redirect it to a file or to your screen like `man -P whoami ls | cat` or `man -P whoami ls > file`, the contents of `file` will be the man page of `ls`.

Why are the two things different? I mean, `man -P whoami ls` and `man -P whoami ls | cat` output different.

Is there any problem?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to set a problem that the players can only use `man` command to do what he want. For example, there is a `flag.txt` in `/tmp` directory and he can use `man -P 'ls /tmp' ls` to get `/tmp` and use `man -P 'cat /tmp/flag.txt' ls` to capture the flag.

Answer (score 2):

`man` doesn't use a pager if the output is not a terminal but a file or a pipe. So the `-P` option is ignored in that case.

Comment: So, can you tell me how to make it possible? Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you actually want to to?

Comment: I want to set a problem that the players can only use `man` command to do what he want. For example, there is a `flag.txt` in /tmp directory and he can use `man -P 'ls /tmp' ls` to get /tmp and use `man -P 'cat /tmp/flag.txt' ls`  to capture the flag.   Thanks a lot!

Comment: The player could do something like `man -P 'sh -c "ls /tmp/ > ls.txt"' ls `